# opencv python Triangular mesh having coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, mesh, triangular

I have a mesh in a stl file ( https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/stlMidpoint.stl )

With this code :

```
from stl import mesh
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import cv2

def unique(a):
   order = np.lexsort(a.T)
   a = a[order]
   diff = np.diff(a, axis=0)
   ui = np.ones(len(a), 'bool')
   ui[1:] = (diff != 0).any(axis=1) 

  return a[ui]

 A = np.loadtxt("vectors.txt")
 A = A[np.logical_not(A[:,2] > 0)]
 uniqA = unique(A)
 coordA = A[:,0:2]
```

I'm able to get the coordinates which has correspondence (I think) to the points of triangles surface.
I'm trying draw the triangles  without success. The points are there but not on a triangles format.
I'm using polines:

```
img= cv2.imread('nimg.jpg')
imgMask = np.ones(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")*255
m_xor= np.ones(imgMask.shape, dtype="uint8") * 255

points = np.array(uniqA[:,0:2], np.int32)
print points
cv2.polylines( m_xor,[points], 1, (0,0,0))
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', m_xor)
```

vectors.txt : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/vectors.txt

nimg: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/nimg.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Using numpy-stl (https://github.com/WoLpH/numpy-stl) I can open, read and render the file easily:

```
from stl import mesh
from matplotlib import collections
from matplotlib import pyplot

# Create a figure and axes
figure, axes = pyplot.subplots()

# Read the STL file
your_mesh = mesh.Mesh.from_file('stlMidPoint.stl')

# Scale the image to the STL dimensions
axes.set_xlim(your_mesh.min_[0], your_mesh.max_[0])
axes.set_ylim(your_mesh.min_[1], your_mesh.max_[1])

# Add the polygons, but only the X and Y axis since it's 2D
axes.add_collection(collections.PolyCollection(your_mesh.vectors[:, :, :2]))

# Make sure the aspect ratio stays correct
pyplot.gca().set_aspect('equal')

# Render!
pyplot.show()
```

The enormous size makes it really slow however.

[image]

Comment: How can I export as numpy vector and overtlay in other images?For instance, how can I apply this mesh on this image https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/La1.png , for instance.

Extracting the numpy array using matplotlib I'll get the points, not the triangles.

Comment: You can use `figure.savefig('image.png', dpi=...)` to store the image as a high-resolution image. Or use `fig.canvas` to access the data directly. The vector is actually already readily available through `your_mesh.vectors[:, :, :2]`

Comment: Do you know a way of drawing in other context different from matplotlib ?

Comment: You could use Pillow (https://pillow.readthedocs.org/) for rendering the image. Just draw the polygons directly: https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.polygon But I have to say that I'm still not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here and if this is the easiest solution for your problem.

Comment: I need to apply this mesh to an image like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/La1.png .
So I need to assure the sizes are the sime, and it's better being using the same "module". I was working with opencv

Comment: Ok, 2 questions in that case.
1. What do you mean with map? Finding the pixels for a triangle?
2. How do the numbers correspond? For example is 1 in the stl file 1 pixel, or is it 10 pixels or something completely different?

Comment: I think that is simple that you're thinking.
I've created the stl using the trimesh module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trimesh/1.12.4 ) .
The initial picture that I've processed to generate the mesh (that I exported in stl) is the LA1. But Like the LA1 there are a lot of different pictures with the same size of LA1.
I need to use the mesh created as a layer to each one of these images for later calculate the areas, Second Moments, etc (per triangle).
The mesh by itself is only a description to the FEM software read

Comment: Mapping the two seems trivial but still requires quite a bit of searching to do correct, with a mesh this size that can still take quite a while since the scale is unknown. That is your biggest problem I think, writing a fast and smart algorithm to map the two together. It might already work by simply mapping through `(max(x_mesh) - min(x_mesh)) / (max(x_image) - min(y_image))` but I'm not entirely certain. You'll have to try that for yourself.

Comment: I've got some questions. Probably I did not understand everything. Is it possible draw the image (LA1) with the mesh at same time?
Assuming that is possible, could I export the "plot" as an image with png format, for instance ?

Comment: Yes you can draw them both at the same time, provided you have a mapping for the pixels in the image to the X and Y coordinates in the mesh. As for storing the image as png, look at my earlier comment regarding `savefig`

Comment: I'm trying overlay both "plots" but is being hard. The axes are completely different, I don't know how to do it. Even the origin (0,0) it's different ! On image it's on top, on the collection is at bottom.

Comment: Correct, that's what makes this a very difficult process. There are algorithms available of course. Some reading material: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching

Comment: I'll try, not trivial task !